# what is the expalanation for this code? I want some clarifications thank u

Tags: php

Our professor told us that we need to explain what does this code mean. I find it difficult because he's not attending to our class. Can someone help me explain this code?

```
<?php
function sequence(){
    $seq1 = $_GET['seq1'];
    $seq = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<=$seq1; $i++){
        $seq = $seq + $i;
        echo $seq. " , ";
        if($i==0) $seq =  $seq + 0;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you run the code and see what it does? Then you can read it line by line and try to figure out what it does.

Comment: Go to https://php.net/, search for the different functions/commands and read up on what they are doing and how they work. What part of the code are you struggling to understand?

Comment: `$seq =  $seq + 0`? Is your professor trying to trick you? That doesn't actually do _anything_. It can be translated to: `1 = 1 + 0` which would just return the same value as it already was.

Comment: Also tell your prof that **a)** `seq1` should be passed as a parameter instead of globals **b)** `seq1` should be validated before using it in a loop as a counter

Comment: It looks like Fibonacci sequence done in iterative way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function `sequence()`.

`$seq1 = $_GET['seq1'];` means you are accessing the url parameter `seq1` in the request. Based on what comes next, it looks like this is going to be a number. This means the url is something like

```
http://some.site.com?seq1=5
```

Now onto the main loop.

```
$seq = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=$seq1; $i++){
    $seq = $seq + $i;
    echo $seq. " , ";
    if($i==0) $seq =  $seq + 0;
}
```

`$seq = 0;` - Assign 0 to a variable called `seq`.

For each number (`i`) in the range 0 to `seq1` inclusive:

- Set `seq` as itself plus `i`.
- Print `<seq> ,`. For example the first thing to be printed would be "`0 ,`".
- The next line adds 0 to seq only on the first item of the loop (when `seq` is also 0), so is completely pointless.

Finally print `<br>`, which is an HTML linebreak tag.